# Trouble with Win 10 writing files to a USB device

Tags: vb.net, usb, usb-flash-drive

I have a USB device with flash memory that looks like a USB FAT16 flash drive to a PC. The device stores VB.net product support software files.

As part of the flash update process the device firmware re-formats flash memory and sets the media change state. Win XP thru Win 8.1 refresh the devices file system and the device shows as an empty drive. From there we copy. Works great.

Windows 10 (since the anniversary update) doesn't pay attention to the media change state. After the device re-formats the flash Win 10 still shows all the files that have been erased. Copying files at this point fails. The only way to recover is to unplug, then plug in the USB connector.

I have tried using `DeviceIoControl(IOCTL_INTERNAL_USB_CYCLE_PORT)` from my application. This only sometimes works.

Is there a better way to programmatically force Win 10 to refresh its view of the USB flash in the device without unplugging it?